# trying to pass header into php file not working

Tags: php

I begin with vars.php:

```
<?php
include('goo.php');
$googl = new goo_gl('http://myurl.info?=sdfdsfs'.uniqid());
$url1 = $googl->result();
$link=$url1; 
$message=$msgarray[rand(0,count($msgarray)-1)];
$picture="http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/4540/7.jpg"; 
?>
```

I want to feel http://mmyurl.info?=sdfdsfs'.uniqid() into  the goo.gl api to spit out a shortened url

and then use this information in vars.php which is in the header''

this info is then used on another page where  $link is called, but i can never get it to work properly

Answer (score 1):

You should give a query string variable a name first:

```
$googl = new goo_gl('http://myurl.info?myvar=sdfdsfs'.uniqid());
```

Now you can access value of `myvar` via `$_GET['myvar']`.